# How to get data from a specific ArrayList row using with a loop?

Tags: java, android

How do I get data from a specific ArrayList row using a loop? I've added those value into **ArrayList** as follow.

```
myArrayList.add("ID007");
myArrayList.add("PPShein");
myArrayList.add("Male");
myArrayList.add("7-Apr-1983");
```

I want to do something like this:

```
for (i=0; i < myarr.size(); i++)
{
    getName = myarr[2].value();
}
```

It's because of I want to display as follow.

```
myTextView.setText(getName); //myName : "ppshein"
```

Comment: @ppshein Can you explain the question a little more?  When you say how to get data from a specific ArrayList row, it sounds like you have an ArrayList fill of arrays, or something representing a row and column structure.  Is that correct?  And what do you need a loop for?  Thanks.

Comment: @Ray Toal, it's because of I don't want to bind ArrayList with setAdapater. What I want is I want to get the data of only one specific row from arraylist to display TextView.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ArrayList has a handy method called `get`, which takes in an index. What you may be used to is using Arrays, such as `array[3]` to access the 4th element. With an ArrayList, use the get method:

```
for(int i = 0; i < myArr.size(); i++) {
  System.out.println(myArr.get(i)); //prints element i 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You just call the row...

```
    String getName;
    int rowValue = 2;
    getName = myarr.get(rowValue);
```

Comment: String should be capitalized there.