# Printing two Strings simultaneously in loop but on separate "paragraphs"

Tags: java, fileinputstream, jcreator

First class:

```
public class Pets
{
    // Instance variables
    private String name;
    private int age;             //in years
    private double weight;       //in pounds

    // Default values for instance variables
    private static final String DEFAULT_NAME = "No name yet." ;
    private static final int DEFAULT_AGE = -1 ;
    private static final double DEFAULT_WEIGHT = -1.0 ;

   /***************************************************
    * Constructors to create objects of type Pet
    ***************************************************/

    // no-argument constructor
    public Pets()
    {
        this(DEFAULT_NAME, DEFAULT_AGE, DEFAULT_WEIGHT) ;
    }
    // only name provided
    public Pets(String initialName)
    {
        this(initialName, DEFAULT_AGE, DEFAULT_WEIGHT) ;
    }
    // only age provided
    public Pets(int initialAge)
    {
        this(DEFAULT_NAME, initialAge, DEFAULT_WEIGHT) ;
    }
    // only weight provided
    public Pets(double initialWeight)
    {
        this(DEFAULT_NAME, DEFAULT_AGE, initialWeight) ;
    }
    // full constructor (all three instance variables provided)
    public Pets(String initialName, int initialAge, double initialWeight)
    {
        setName(initialName) ;
        setAge(initialAge) ;
        setWeight(initialWeight) ;
    }

   /****************************************************************
    * Mutators and setters to update the Pet.  Setters for age and
    * weight validate reasonable weights are specified
    ****************************************************************/

    // Mutator that sets all instance variables
    public void set(String newName, int newAge, double newWeight)
    {
        setName(newName) ;
        setAge(newAge) ;
        setWeight(newWeight) ;
    }

    // Setters for each instance variable (validate age and weight)
    public void setName(String newName)
    {
        name = newName;
    }
    public void setAge(int newAge)
    {
        if ((newAge < 0) && (newAge != DEFAULT_AGE))
        {
            System.out.println("Error: Invalid age.");
            System.exit(99);
        }
        age = newAge;
    }
    public void setWeight(double newWeight)
    {
        if ((newWeight < 0.0) && (newWeight != DEFAULT_WEIGHT))
        {
            System.out.println("Error: Invalid weight.");
            System.exit(98);
        }
        weight = newWeight;
    }

   /************************************
    * getters for name, age, and weight
    ************************************/
    public String getName( )
    {
        return name ;
    }
    public int getAge( )
    {
        return age ;
    }
    public double getWeight( )
    {
        return weight ;
    }

   /****************************************************
    * toString() shows  the pet's name, age, and weight
    * equals() compares all three instance variables
    ****************************************************/
    public String toString( )
    {
        return ("Name: " + name + "  Age: " + age + " years"
                       + "   Weight: " + weight + " pounds");
    }
    public boolean equals(Pets anotherPet)
    {
        if (anotherPet == null)
        {
            return false ;
        }
        return ((this.getName().equals(anotherPet.getName())) &&
                (this.getAge() == anotherPet.getAge()) &&
                (this.getWeight() == anotherPet.getWeight())) ;
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
import java.util.Scanner ;
import java.io.FileInputStream ;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException ;
import java.io.IOException ;

public class PetsMain 
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in) ;
        System.out.println("Please enter the number of pets") ;
        int numberOfPets = keyboard.nextInt() ;

        String fileName = "pets.txt" ; 
        FileInputStream fileStream = null ;

        String workingDirectory = System.getProperty("user.dir") ;
        System.out.println("Working Directory for this program: " + workingDirectory) ;

        try
        {
            String absolutePath = workingDirectory + "\\" + fileName ;
            System.out.println("Trying to open: " + absolutePath) ;
            fileStream = new FileInputStream(absolutePath) ;
            System.out.println("Opened the file ok.\n") ;
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("File \'" + fileName + "\' is missing") ;
            System.out.println("Exiting program. ") ;
            System.exit(0) ;
        }

        Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(fileStream) ;
        int sumAge = 0 ;
        double sumWeight = 0 ;

        String petName = "Pet Name" ;
        String dogAge = "Age" ;
        String dogWeight = "Weight" ;
        String line = "--------------" ;
        System.out.printf("%11s %15s %19s %n", petName, dogAge, dogWeight) ;
        System.out.printf("%s %17s %17s %n", line, line, line) ;
        for (int counter = 0; counter < numberOfPets; counter++) 
        {
            fileScanner.useDelimiter(",") ;                
            String name = fileScanner.next() ;
            fileScanner.useDelimiter(",") ;
            int age = fileScanner.nextInt() ;
            fileScanner.useDelimiter("[,\\s]") ;
            double weight = fileScanner.nextDouble() ;
            Pets pets = new Pets(name, age, weight) ; 
            sumAge += age ; 
            sumWeight += weight ;
            System.out.printf("%-15s %15d %18s %n", name, age, weight) ; 

            System.out.println(pets.toString()) ; // Print until above is done

        }

        /*How do I make this? 
         Smallest pet: Name: Tweety  Age: 2 years  Weight: 0.1 pounds
         Largest pet:  Name: Dumbo  Age: 6 years  Weight: 2000.0 pounds
         Youngest pet: Name: Fido  Age: 1 years  Weight: 15.0 pounds
         Oldest pet:   Name: Sylvester  Age: 10 years  Weight: 8.3 pounds
        */

        System.out.println("\nThe total weight is " + sumWeight) ;
        System.out.println("\nThe total age is " + sumAge) ;

        try
        {
            fileStream.close() ;
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            // don't do anything
        }

    }

}
```

Keep in mind that only the Main class is the one we can make changes to. 
In the Main class, the part where I noted

> // Print until above is done
>   it prints the following:

```
       Pet Name             Age              Weight
--------------    --------------    --------------
Fido                          1               15.0
Name: Fido  Age: 1 years   Weight: 15.0 pounds

Tweety                      2                0.1
Name:
Tweety  Age: 2 years   Weight: 0.1 pounds

Sylvester                  10                8.3
Name:
Sylvester  Age: 10 years   Weight: 8.3 pounds

Fido                        1               15.0
Name:
Fido  Age: 1 years   Weight: 15.0 pounds

Dumbo                       6             2000.0
Name:
Dumbo  Age: 6 years   Weight: 2000.0 pounds
```

Is it possible to make it print on a different "paragraph"? For example, like this:

```
Pet Name             Age              Weight
--------------    --------------    -------------- 
Fido                          1               15.0

Tweety                      2                0.1

Sylvester                  10                8.3

Fido                        1               15.0

Dumbo                       6             2000.0

Name: Fido  Age: 1 years   Weight: 15.0 pounds
Name: Tweety  Age: 2 years   Weight: 0.1 pounds
Name: Sylvester  Age: 10 years   Weight: 8.3 pounds
Name: Fido  Age: 1 years   Weight: 15.0 pounds
Name: Dumbo  Age: 6 years   Weight: 2000.0 pounds
```

I tried to create a different loop for the second part but I ran into the problem of trying to access the pets. The only one that would access was the last one used. Any thoughts?

UPDATE: The major issue is solved but I have a minor issue left. When I run the program I get this:

```
Name: Fido  Age: 1 years   Weight: 15.0 pounds
Name: 
Tweety  Age: 2 years   Weight: 0.1 pounds
Name: 
Sylvester  Age: 10 years   Weight: 8.3 pounds
Name: 
Fido  Age: 1 years   Weight: 15.0 pounds
Name: 
Dumbo  Age: 6 years   Weight: 2000.0 pounds
```

Why aren't the rest pets aligned with Name?

Comment: your equals is wrong, you should override equals(Object o). what do you mean: print on different paragraph? it's a command prompt print, not a word document

Comment: That's not how you do it. You should first collect the pets being entered (into a `Collection`), then loop through that to print them out.

Comment: @Stultuske thats why I put quotations around print. I gave an example of what I meant.

Comment: @daniu Collection? How so?

Comment: of course that's possible, it's also quite simple. Daniu's response should be able to help you, it's about the most precise we can get without writing the code for you. just a hint: a Collection can be iterated over more than one time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way to store individually every pet is to create an `ArrayList` is like a collection where you store every pet and you can always acces to their infor knowing the index on it.

As in the code, we declare the variables out of the loop so we can access those variables in hole class, then we initialize the object and we create the ArrayList (remember to create an empty constructor in the Pets class.

When you have the loop to read the file you add every pet to the ArrayList with:

`pets.add(new Pets(name,age,weight));`

So out of the read loop we create an other loop to acces to every index of the ArrayList, if you only want 1 pet you could make a loop to find an exactly name or things like that is more useful than only print and never store the pets. So basically you can acces to the pet with `pets.get(x)` where x is the index of the pet.

```
public class PetsMain {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // We declare variables here
        String name;
        int age;
        double weight;
        Pets pet = new Pets(); // Initialize Object
        ArrayList<Pets> pets = new ArrayList<Pets>(); // We create the ArrayList


        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in) ;
        System.out.println("Please enter the number of pets") ;
        int numberOfPets = keyboard.nextInt() ;

        String fileName = "pets.txt" ; 
        FileInputStream fileStream = null ;

        String workingDirectory = System.getProperty("user.dir") ;
        System.out.println("Working Directory for this program: " + workingDirectory) ;

        try
        {
            String absolutePath = workingDirectory + "\\" + fileName ;
            System.out.println("Trying to open: " + absolutePath) ;
            fileStream = new FileInputStream(absolutePath) ;
            System.out.println("Opened the file ok.\n") ;
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("File \'" + fileName + "\' is missing") ;
            System.out.println("Exiting program. ") ;
            System.exit(0) ;
        }

        Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(fileStream) ;
        int sumAge = 0 ;
        double sumWeight = 0 ;

        String petName = "Pet Name" ;
        String dogAge = "Age" ;
        String dogWeight = "Weight" ;
        String line = "--------------" ;
        System.out.printf("%11s %15s %19s %n", petName, dogAge, dogWeight) ;
        System.out.printf("%s %17s %17s %n", line, line, line) ;
        for (int counter = 0; counter < numberOfPets; counter++) 
        {
            fileScanner.useDelimiter(",") ;                
            name = fileScanner.next() ;
            fileScanner.useDelimiter(",") ;
            age = fileScanner.nextInt() ;
            fileScanner.useDelimiter("[,\\s]") ;
            weight = fileScanner.nextDouble() ;
            sumAge += age ; 
            sumWeight += weight ;
            System.out.printf("%-15s %15d %18s %n", name, age, weight) ; 

            // **We add the pet to the collection
            pets.add(new Pets(name,age,weight)); // Adding it to the ArrayList
        }

        // Then we acces to the ArrayList and we print what we want.
        for(int x=0; x < pets.size(); x++){
            System.out.print(pets.get(x).toString());
        }

        System.out.println("\nThe total weight is " + sumWeight) ;
        System.out.println("\nThe total age is " + sumAge) ;

        try
        {
            fileStream.close() ;
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            // don't do anything
        }
    }

}
```

Hope it helped you and if you have any questions add a comment :)

Here you can easy find info about storing objects on Arraylist and print it:

[How to add an object to an ArrayList in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19616972/how-to-add-an-object-to-an-arraylist-in-java)

[How to get data from a specific ArrayList row using with a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142340/how-to-get-data-from-a-specific-arraylist-row-using-with-a-loop)

Comment: When you created the ArrayList, it says it can't find symbol. Why is that?

Comment: Solved. I forgot to import ArrayList. Thanks!

Comment: I have updated my initial post, I hope you can help me with that minor issue.

Comment: Can be only 2 things: The way you store the data, check the reader of the pets file, or could be the way you're printing but I dont see anything weird so probably is the reader. @TomásPalamás

Answer (score 1):

Just change `System.out.printf("%-15s %15d %18s %n", name, age, weight) ;`
into

```
List<Pet> pets = new ArrayList<>();
pets.add(new Pet(name, age, weight));
```

Then you can print the collection with for each loop.

Comment: It says it cannot find symbol.

Answer (score 1):

You do something like this:

```
// allows you to store the pets that were entered
Collection<Pets> petsCollection = new ArrayList<>();

// loop and have the user enter pets
for (int i = 0; i < petCount; i++) {
    // your code
    fileScanner.useDelimiter(",") ;                
    String name = fileScanner.next() ;
    fileScanner.useDelimiter(",") ;
    int age = fileScanner.nextInt() ;
    fileScanner.useDelimiter("[,\\s]") ;
    double weight = fileScanner.nextDouble();
    Pets pets = new Pets(name, age, weight); 
    // add to collection
    petsCollection.add(pets);
}
```

Now you have all your pets in the collection, and you can iterate it to do all kind of things, like print:

```
petsCollection.forEach(pet -> {
    System.out.printf("Pet: %s age: %d weight: %d%n", pet.getName(), pet.getAge(), pet.getWeight());
});
```

or get the youngest pet

```
int minAge = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
for (Pets pet : petsCollection) {
    minAge = Math.min(minAge, pet.getAge());
}
System.out.printf("The youngest pet is %d%n", minAge);
```

There are more elegant ways of doing this (using Streams), but I think it's best to start like this.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing both lines in the same loop, so they always be in the same paragraph.

```
System.out.printf("%-15s %15d %18s %n", name, age, weight) ; 
System.out.println(pets.toString()) ; // Print until above is done
```

The easiest way for doing this is to store the pets in an array and then iterate it when you finish the other loop.

Something like this:

```
List<Pets> petList = new ArrayList<Pets>();
for (int counter = 0; counter < numberOfPets; counter++) 
{
    fileScanner.useDelimiter(",") ;                
    String name = fileScanner.next() ;
    fileScanner.useDelimiter(",") ;
    int age = fileScanner.nextInt() ;
    fileScanner.useDelimiter("[,\\s]") ;
    double weight = fileScanner.nextDouble() ;
    Pets pets = new Pets(name, age, weight) ; 
    sumAge += age ; 
    sumWeight += weight ;
    System.out.printf("%-15s %15d %18s %n", name, age, weight) ; 
    petList.add(pets);
}

for(Pets pet : petList{
    System.out.println(pets.toString()) ;
}
```